# Xcode 9 is taking too much time to load the Application

Tags: ios, xcode9

I just installed the Xcode 9 for iOS 11 for my older project to update.
 But it's taking too much time to load the app in Simulator as well as in iOS devices.

Are there any settings that I need to change in Xcode?

Also, I found one major issue is hitting the Mac machine.

Answer (score 1):

I found another problem with Xcode recommended settings for Pods.
If you accept recommended settings, Xcode changes optimization level for Pods project to "Fast, Whole Module Optimization". It changes both of Debug and Release. You can change manually only for Release. That fixed my unnecessary building problem.

If you accepted recommended settings before, close Xcode and update and re-install pods. Than change optimization level for Pods project manually.

[image]

---

***My First Answer***

Commit changes and try again. It worked for me. 
If you don't use git or another source control, you can find commit in Xcode's "Source Control" menu.

I'm not sure but It's good to clean compiled things too.
(on XCode menu > Product > Clean)

Comment: This works I think. If anybody is facing any issue, do give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes delayed launching is because of large chunks of data being bundled with the app.

For eg: If you are uplaoding a json with huge data, the app will take time to process , bundle and install it which subsequently will lead to a delayed launch of the app.

So you need to verify whether something like that has been added to your project.

Comment: I'm running Xcode version 9.2 latest one... and it takes too much times even for loading new projects, also i've a macbook pro 2016 with touch bar, 16GB ram, i7, memory pressure Normal :/